# SparkSession version trouble in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I've read [this article](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/sort-merge-join-spark-sql/read) and copipasted the Sort-Merge Join Example, but when I'm trying to build the project I'm getting the following error:

> object SparkSession is not a member of package org.apache.spark.sql

I've seen many questions about this error, and the answers were that they used an old version of Spark. However I mentioned in build.sbt version 2.1 of Spark as they use in the example on that website.

Here is my build.sbt:

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark SQL dependency is missing

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % 2.1.0
```